# use pol2cart on data and get image out of it

Tags: matlab

Hello i need to convert an polar data (512x600000) into Cartesian and plot as an image.

I think i can use "pol2cart" but I have problems with the implementation.
At the end i would like to get a picture out.

This is my ground structure but i'm not sure how to proceed.

```
data = poldata; %polardata rows - radius, columns angle
...
theta = [];  %not sure how to split my matrix
rho = [];
...
[X,Y] = pol2cart(theta ,rho); %(angle, radius)
imagesc(X,Y)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I want to split this big Matrix so that i can use a code like this:
theta = [0 pi/4 pi/2 pi]
rho = [5 5 10 10]
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,rho)

the image with imagesc should color one pixel on a cartesian grid depending on its value

Comment: `pol2cart` will transform vectors of `(r,theta)` values into vectors of corresponding `(x,y)`, but in your matrix you seem to say that the `r` values are the _rows_ and the `theta` values are the _lines_. The actual numeric values in your matrix are a scalar value `v` (with `v=f(r,theta)`). To get a matrix `v=f(x,y)`, you need to be able to build your vector `r` and `theta` first. For that you need to know how the matrix is built. We cannot guess it for you (example, Let's assume the first column is theta=0, then what value of theta is the second column ? the third column ?)

Comment: As @Hoki explained, you don't have pairs `(rho, theta)`, your matrix has scalars. Where are `rho` and `theta` coming from? For example, what is the value of `rho` for the first row (or any row) of `poldata`? You need 512 values of `rho`, one for each row. Likewise, what is the value of `theta` for the first column? (or for any column). You need 6e5 values of `theta`, one for each column. Are the values of `rho` and `theta` proportional to their indices? E.g. `theta = linspace(0,2*pi,6e5)` (you'd need a way to exclude 2*pi, but we can address that later).